# ASP.NET MVC 3: I cannot navigate to my "Content" directory until authorized

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

All, I am deploying an MVC 3 Application to a test server for the first time.  The app runs just as expected locally out of Cassini.  However, On the server through IIS, it will not display CSS until I am authenticated.  If I try to navigate to localhost/Content/Site.css, it redirects me to the login page.  I checked in IIS and anonymous authentication is enabled.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.  For me, the answer was to give **Read** permissions to the folder to **IUSR** as well as **IIS_IUSRS**.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to  your web.config.  You have to tell asp.net that the following directory can be accessed whether you are authenticated or not.  This belongs in the configuration setting in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
...

<location path="Content">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

...

<system.web>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
.....

</configuration>
```

Comment: I actually already have this.  Except I also have a line for <allow users="?" /> for those that are not authenticated.

Comment: This is an excerpt from mine.  I've excluded quite a bit.  Be sure you have a <location> element that is a direct descendant of the <configuration> element.

Comment: I'm still not getting any css, and also not able to navigate directly to my Content/site.css file.

Comment: You are editing the web.config in the root directory of your project correct?  Not the web.config in the /Views directory.

Comment: It might help if you copy your web.config into the question.

Comment: It looks like it was a permissions issue.  I copied an entire directory over the directory in my wwwroot dir.  I had to re-add Network Service and IUser as "users" having access to my app directory.

Comment: Not for sure why file permissions would trigger asp.net forms authentication to redirect you to the login page.  But who knows, anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the permissions on the files and make sure they match the files you can match. Secondly check your web.config to ensure you are not using authorization elements in there such as:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: ok cool - so it was permissions. Also as per the prior mentioning of the authorize nodes in the web.config, this is _not_ the general recommended way of doing mvc security. One should use the [Authorize] attribute. Sure - at times you need to protect folders with other content, but anything related to mvc specific items should use the authorize attribute and not the web forms way of using authorization attributes as in MVC multiple urls can at times lead to the same controller/action method. Protecting the URL then is very error prone in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC
>   application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is
>   to apply the [Authorize] attribute to each controller and action
>   method (except for the login/register methods). Making security
>   decisions based on the current area is a Very Bad Thing and will open
>   your application to vulnerabilities.

You can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

You can control your authentication method in your **web.config** file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="2880" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

then you have to use the [Authorize] attribute for the controller/action you want to protect.
Generally you don't want to protect the Account controller.

Another useful [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization.aspx).